# Why must translate() be in draw() in p5?

Tags: python, html5-canvas, processing, p5.js

Using [p5](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library ported to python. By default the coordinate system has 0,0 starting at the top left like HTML canvas. I'm trying to convert this to a cartesian plane with 0,0 at the center using `translate()` then draw a circle at `0,0` to confirm it's at the center.

It works, but only when I have `translate()` in `def draw()` instead of `def setup()`

This works:

```
from p5 import *

def setup():
    size(900, 900)

def draw():
    translate(width/2, height/2)
    circle(0, 0, 50) # draws circle at center

run()
```

This does not work:

```
from p5 import *

def setup():
    size(900, 900)
    translate(width/2, height/2)

def draw():
    circle(0, 0, 50) # draws circle at top left

run()
```

I've confirmed using `print()` statements that `run()` calls `setup()` before it calls `draw()`, so the translation should be happening before `circle()` is executed.

Why must I put `translate()` in `draw()` and not `setup()` if `setup()` is running first? Is the translation resetting every `draw()` execution?

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE of some kind?  The p5 code looks specifically for `__main__.setup`.  Have you put in `print` statements to see if they actually get run?  You cam try overriding their default lookup by doing `run(setup,draw)`.

Comment: vscode. I put print() at the beginning of both functions and they were executed in my terminal in order, so run() must be running them.

Comment: I tried tracing through the code to see if they set the translation after, but `p5` dives into `vispy` and then into OpenGL, and I'm afraid I lost interest.  You can try following that thread if you really want to get to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually documented [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) last paragraph (emphasis mine):

> **It is important to note that the drawing coordinate system will be reset at the beginning of each `draw()` call.** If any transformations are performed within `draw()` (ex: `scale`, `rotate`, `translate`), their effects will be undone at the beginning of `draw()`, so transformations will not accumulate over time.

So it's not strictly Python-specific, `p5.js` itself specifices so and `translate` in `setup` has no effect.